# Python replace & with &amp;

Tags: python, regex, xml

I want python regular expression to replace `&` with `&amp;` in xml obj. But not replace `&lt;` or `&gt;`

Example:

```
dataobj = '<Style width="100.000000%"/><Data&><![CDATA[<p>TEST TEST &lt; TEST 10&gt; starts &" and T&L'
```

And my expected output should be

```
outputdata = '<Style width="100.000000%"/><Data&amp;><![CDATA[<p>TEST TEST &lt; TEST 10&gt; starts &amp;" and T&amp;L'
```

I can strictly say for `&lt;` `&gt;` `&eq;` `&in;` `&amp;` should not change anything. where ever i found `&` should replace with `&amp;` but not for `&lt;` `&gt;` `&eq;` `&in;` `&amp;`

Comment: You need to use an XML parser / generator instead of manually dealing with escapes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Here is a list of XML parsers in python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python

Answer (score 0):

I think a negative lookahead might be sufficient, although depending on the exact use case an XML parser may be better:

```
import re
dataobj = '<Style width="100.000000%"/><Data&><![CDATA[<p>TEST TEST &lt; TEST 10&gt; starts &" and T&L'

amp = re.compile(r'&(?![lg]t;)')
print(re.sub(amp,'&amp;',dataobj))
```

produces

```
<Style width="100.000000%"/><Data&amp;><![CDATA[<p>TEST TEST &lt; TEST 10&gt; starts &amp;" and T&amp;L
```